# why arabic is not displaying left to right on kindle

Tags: kindle, publishing

I uploaded a docx file in arabic to kdp following the required formatting. The book displays  correctly on Amazon's look inside feature but a test buy did not display properly for the buyer on kindle pc app in France. I tried converting the source doc to mobi online and this file will not display properly on my 2019 kindle paperwhite which 'does not support left alignment'.
I thought kindle supported arabic since June 2018. Does anybody know how to solve this display problem?